Need help better understanding rsync logs
I have a large rsync running from userscripts transferring about 9tb from a local synology to my unraid and it seems to be going well so far but upon looking at the log from the transfer I'm confused as to why there are simultaneous transfers going out of chronological/alphabetic order. I hope I'm making sense but there's in the root of the server are years 2003-2023 and here it looks like it's mainly transferring /2009/ but then sometimes is jumping to /2005/ both of which are in the root. Happy to provide more info if necessary.
Log:
SERVER/2009/Jul 25, 2009/IMG_1172.JPG

32.77K   1%   70.64kB/s    0:00:39  
2.86M 100%    5.16MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#5306, ir-chk=1108/6804)
SERVER/2009/Jul 25, 2009/IMG_1173.JPG

32.77K   1%   53.51kB/s    0:00:57  2005/
2005/Picture 005.jpg

3.12M 100%    4.70MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#5307, ir-chk=1107/6804)

32.77K   1%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  SERVER/2009/Jul 25, 2009/IMG_1174.JPG

32.77K   1%   49.16kB/s    0:00:57  
 1.64M 100%   76.82MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1122/1260)
2005/Rover.jpg

2.85M 100%    3.97MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#5308, ir-chk=1106/6804)

32.77K  12%  744.19kB/s    0:00:00  SERVER/2009/Jul 25, 2009/IMG_1175.JPG

        253.73K 100%    5.15MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, ir-chk=1121/1260)
2005/Ski close.jpg

Rsync command:
rsync -avPh /mnt/remotes/SOURCE/* /mnt/user/SynologyData >> /mnt/user/SynologyData/rsyncfullphototransfer.log 2>&1
Directory:
/2003/
/2004/
...
/2022/

